# Function overloading is not implemented

Tags: typescript

A request requests different interfaces according to different input values, and returns different return values. code show as below:

```
enum E {
  A,
  B,
  C,
}
interface Fn {
  (arg: E.A): Number;
  (arg: E.B): String;
  (arg: E.C): null;
}
const fn: Fn = (arg: E) => {
  switch (arg) {
    case E.A:
      return 1;
    case E.B:
      return '1';
    default:
      return null;
  }
};
```

It can be inferred correctly when used, but getSelectList reports an error message:

```
const fn: Fn
'fn' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
Type '(arg: E) => 1 | "1" | null' is not assignable to type 'Fn'.
  Type 'string | number | null' is not assignable to type 'Number'.
    Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Number'.ts(2322)
```

seem like thishttps://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014

```
enum E {
  A,
  B,
  C,
}
type FF<A extends E> = A extends E.A
  ? Number
  : A extends E.B
    ? String
    : null;

const fn = <A extends E>(arg: A): FF<A> => {
  switch (arg) {
    case E.A:
// error: Type '1' is not assignable to type 'FF<A>'
      return 1;
    case E.B:
      return '1';
    default:
      return null;
  }
};

fn(E.A);
```

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in the question to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/oN5MPN), where the only issues present are the ones you're asking about.  This will make it easier for others to demonstrate your problem for themselves and produce useful and targeted answers that they themselves have tested.  Right now there are too many undeclared external types for me to make much sense of what's going on without pretending to be a compiler myself, which I'm not particularly good at.

Comment: oky~ I corrected it

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround:

```js
enum E {
    A,
    B,
    C,
}

function fn(arg: E.A): number;
function fn(arg: E.B): string;
function fn(arg: E.C): null;
function fn(arg: E) {
    switch (arg) {
        case E.A:
            return 1 as number;
        case E.B:
            return '1' as string;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
const result = fn(E.A) // number
const result2 = fn(E.B) // string
const result3 = fn(E.C) // null
```

P.S. Try to avoid constructor types like `String` | `NUmber`, use primitives as `string` | `number`